# Is inheritance a good tool to design a builder/factory

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory, builder

I have several complex classes, that are constructed using separate creator classes that inherits from the class to create.

One example might be a graph that is constructed from unordered data.

```
class Graph{
  //....
  public:
   void showData(); 
  protected: 
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > mConnectedData;

}

class GraphCreator:private Graph{
  public:
    //...
    void construct();
  private:
   std::map<double,int> mSomeHelperContainer;
   //...
}
```

For the construction I need many helper functions and also helper data, which I put in another class GraphCreator. Since many graph related functions are also necessary and since I need the data of the graph at any case I use private inheritance.
Since this is by no means the famous is-a relation and since private inheritance is generally considered a hint for bad design I have some doubts:
Is this a good Idea and one appropriate way to design a factory or are there some major drawbacks that I have no thought about ?
What would be a better way of designing a such a factory ?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the answers so far !
Some additional information to make the reason for the currently used approach clearer.
I cannot use a static creation method (far too many state variables in the Creator) and I have another constraint: 
I want to provide the Graph independent from the creator (e.g together with a read from file method) in a library to other people. 
Those should not have to care about the creator. Therefore I am also a little unsure about friend usage, since it adds code inside the Graph class.

Comment: You are right, this smells like bad design. If you post some more code (which uses the inherited stuff) we can suggest alternatives.

Comment: Here is an excellent example of the builder pattern in case it helps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: What is so bad about giving Graph a public Interface to consistently build it up from the outside and we let GraphCreator do that job?

Comment: @user331471: The information to build the graph from scratch are not available in the library the graph is included in (Too much code,too many dependencies etc.). The only provided interface to be provided to construct the graph is a file reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good way (inheritance from anything with data rarely is).

The traditional approach is to either:

- make `GraphCreator` a `friend` of `Graph`
- implement the method as a `static` `Build` method in `Graph` (directly)

The decision mainly depends on whether you need the "factory" to be stateful. A `class` is used to represent state, which a method cannot do.

- Therefore if you need state you need a `class` to store it, and thus `GraphCreator` is your best bet.
- For a stateless approach, the `static` method is much more lightweight.

If you are undecided, pick the easiest (`static` method) and see how far it goes :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I cannot use the static method (far too many state variables in the Creator) and I have another constraint: I want to provide the Graph together with a fileReader in a library to other people, which should not have to care about the creator. Therefore I am also a little unsure about friend usage. Since it adds code inside the Graph class. Inheriting from Graph would have no impact on the Graph class.

Comment: @Martin: the friend is not a problem because you can befriend a class that is forward-declared. So people will know that a `class GraphCreator;` exists, and that it is a `friend` of `Graph`, but they will not know what this class is.

Comment: Fair enough, that's true indeed! Up to now I rarely use friend since I once read that it introduces even tighter coupling than inheritance. Why do you prefer friend to inheritance in this case ?

Comment: @Martin: It's true, but it can be an advantage. Of course, if you only ever had two classes `Graph` and `GraphCreator`, it might not be much of an advantage; however to expose some details to `GraphCreator` you need to "pollute" the `protected` section of `Graph` and end up accidentally exposing them to all the derived classes of `Graph` at the same time. With `friend`, you pay the cost of tightly coupling `Graph` and `GraphCreator` and in exchange you gain much better encapsulation for all the other derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

A rule of thumb that I adopted from [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.3) is

> Use composition when you can, private inheritance when you have to.

One specific example of the "you have to" is when the class from which you inherit has some virtual or pure virtual functions that you must implement in order to use your private base: you simply cannot do it without inheriting.

It does not look from your description that using inheritance is unavoidable; therefore, I think it is best to use composition.

Comment: I don't think composition is even necessary here: the builder (`GraphCreator`) creates `Graph`s but does not need to aggregate any (if I understood the question correctly).

Comment: @LucTouraille My understanding is that in the current dessign the builder needs to store the instance on which it currently operates. It is certainly possible to make that instance external to the builder, and pass it on each call to helper methods that are otherwise static, but that would be a more significant refactoring.